How to update all NPM packages to the latest version compatible version
I've an Angular project, composed of several projects. Currently here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "my-product",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max-http-header-size=100000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:dev": "ng build  --configuration development",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:ci": "ng test --code-coverage --watch=false --karma-config karma.conf.ci.js",
    "lint": "ng lint --fix",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^18.1.0",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^8.0.7",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^18.0.0",
    "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^18.0.0",
    "@ngxs/store": "^18.0.0",
    "angular-gridster2": "^18.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "ngx-logger": "^5.0.9",
    "primeflex": "^3.2.1",
    "primeng": "^17.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "18.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "18.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "18.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "18.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "18.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.1.0",
    "@ngxs/schematics": "^0.0.1-alpha.5",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.29.0",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint": "^8.18.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-ban": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.2",
    "karma": "~6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "ng-mocks": "^14.13.0",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "prettier-eslint": "^13.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^22.13.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "~5.5.3"
  }
}

With npx npm-check-updates, I found that I've several packages outdated, typically, all the stuff around ESLint:
 eslint                             ^8.18.0  →    ^9.7.0
 eslint-config-prettier              ^8.5.0  →    ^9.1.0
 eslint-plugin-prettier              ^4.0.0  →    ^5.2.1
 eslint-plugin-unused-imports        ^2.0.0  →    ^4.0.1

How am I supposed to update all the packages to the latest version that is compatible for all the projects, respecting the dependencies?
With npx npm-check-updates -i, I can select all the packages that needs to be udpated. To start simple, I tried to only update the one that are related to ESLint.
But now when I do a npm install I get plenty of errors due to dependencies:
npm warn ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm warn While resolving: vs-central@0.0.0
npm warn Found: eslint@8.57.0
npm warn node_modules/eslint
npm warn   dev eslint@"^9.7.0" from the root project
npm warn   17 more (@angular-eslint/builder, ...)
npm warn
npm warn Could not resolve dependency:
npm warn peer eslint@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.62.0
npm warn node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm warn   dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^5.29.0" from the root project
npm warn   1 more (eslint-plugin-unused-imports)

npm warn ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

npm warn While resolving: vs-central@0.0.0
npm warn Found: eslint@8.57.0
npm warn node_modules/eslint
npm warn   dev eslint@"^9.7.0" from the root project
npm warn   17 more (@angular-eslint/builder, ...)
npm warn
npm warn Could not resolve dependency:
npm warn peer eslint@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/parser@5.62.0
npm warn node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
npm warn   dev @typescript-eslint/parser@"^5.29.0" from the root project
npm warn   1 more (@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin)
[... Plenty of others errors ...]

How can I update those packages without breaking my app?

...npm update? Sounds like what you're trying to do is a major version update which by definitely is not compatible.

do not update everything to the latest version. Many packages depend on  older versions of some other packages and that will cause issue.. Using the latest version is only a good idea if you want to use the new feature added in it. otherwise, use whichever version gets the work done and whichever version you are comfortable working in.

@AniketPandey Thank you for the suggestion, but that's not about updating to the last version. We just updated our angular from 14 to 18, and we wanted to make sure that the matching libraries were also up to date, because it seems that the ng lint command has some issues with our current version.

@jonrsharpe can you provide the full command? How do I know what is the latest version that I can update to with all the dependencies in the project?

npm update is the full command to update all npm packages to the latest (semver-)compatible version. Major version upgrades are generally not semver-compatible (unless you had something very broad like >=x or *). Upgrading ESLint to the latest (v9) certainly isn't going to work when your TypeScript-ESLint packages are two (nearly three) major versions behind, as the message you're looking at makes clear.

You need to first install the major important packages and then start building up on that. Otherwise, this task is going to be a mess as there will be lot of conflicts and issues like some package needs an older version to run but you updated to the latest version. Or you can try resolving those errors one by one. There is no easy fix for this situation. Been there, done that.
